# How to loop over pandas dataframe and generate new rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
User    app      percent
1        a         0.8
1        b         0.3
1        c         0.2
1        d         0.9
1        e         0.6
1        f         0.8
1        g         0.4
1        h         0.2
1        i         0.1
1        j         0.6
```

Each user has at least 10 apps.

I need a loop that will add to each user rows with the value of 0.5 in the percent column.

The sum of rows will be 50 for each user.

For example, user number 1 has 10 apps so the loop needs to go over 10 values in the table and generate 40 rows of 0.5 value.

The final cell will multiply the 10 values (percent column) in the above table and multiply this with 0.5 value-40 times.

This is the calculation for user number 1:

```
  0.8* 0.3* 0.2* 0.9* 0.6* 0.8* 0.4* 0.2* 0.1* 0.6* 0.5* 0.5*.....*0.5
```

Comment: Hi. Are the apps are still the same, or add new app for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`GroupBy.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html) for each user and multiple by `Series` created by [`numpy.power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) - `0.5` by Series created by substracted `50` from `a['size']`:

Sample for `8` rows instead `50` for better verifying:

```
print (df)
   User app  percent
0     1   a      0.8
1     1   b      0.3
2     1   c      0.2
3     1   d      0.9
4     1   e      0.6
5     1   f      0.8
6     2   g      0.4
7     2   h      0.2
8     2   i      0.1
9     2   j      0.6
```

---

```
a = df.groupby('User')['percent'].agg(['size','prod'])
print (a)
      size      prod
User                
1        6  0.020736
2        4  0.004800

b = a['prod'] * np.power(0.5, a['size'].rsub(8))
#same as
#b = a['prod'] * np.power(0.5, 8 - a['size'])
print (b)
User
1    0.005184
2    0.000300
dtype: float64
```

And for `DataFrame` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (a['prod'] * np.power(0.5, a['size'].rsub(8))).reset_index(name='col')
print (df1)
   User       col
0     1  0.005184
1     2  0.000300
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're looking for -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('File.csv')

df_g = df.groupby(['User'])['percent'].agg(['prod', 'count'])
df_g['final_prod'] = df_g[['prod', 'count']].apply(lambda x: x['prod'] * (0.5 ** (50-x['count'])), axis=1)
print(df_g.drop(['prod', 'count'], axis=1).reset_index())
```

Output

```
     User    final_prod
0     1  9.052455e-17
```

Answer (score 0):

I may give an example with only for user 1. Here i generate a similar data, and then multiply it 5 times to get 5 repeats of each row, so 50 rows in total. Then i make it as a dataframe.

```
import pandas
import numpy
import random

user = [1 for i in range(10)]
app = ['a'+str(i+1) for i in range(10)]
percent = [0.1 + i*0.1 for i in range(10)]

data = list(zip(user, app, percent));
data_to_edit = 5*data;

df = pandas.DataFrame(data_to_edit, columns=['User','App','Percent']);
```

Now create the product of the first 10 of percent data (original data).

```
percent_product=numpy.prod(df['Percent'][0:9]);
```

Now all we need to do is edit the remaining 40 rows, but only for the `'Percent'` column.

```
for i in df.index[10:]:
    df['Percent'][i] = percent_product*(0.5**(i-9));
```

Now the first 10 rows will be the same, but the other rows are multiplied by increasing multiple of 0.5.

Is this what you mean..?